# Using the readahead syscall in C in the linux environment

Tags: c, linux

I am interested in using the readahead syscall in a c program. Currently I have opened a file for reading with a call to open(). Once I find a character, say the letter 'b', I want to test whether the following letters are 'ar' to make up the string 'bar'. The string will be an arbitrary length so I will have to cycle through. I was thinking something like:

```
f = open(file, readpermissions);
read(fdr, buf, size);
if (buf[0] == word[i]) {
   lookahead(.....);
}
```

Something along those lines. Currently my buffer is reading one character at a time plus the NULL terminator if it exists.

Any tips on the proper use of readahead to accomplish this?

Comment: `readahead` is for pre-fetching - it doesn't seem to help here at all. Why are you certain you want to use it?

Comment: Why dont you use `<stdio.h>`, `fopen`, `fgetc` in a loop? You'll get buffered IO which is generally more efficient.

Comment: Did you RTFM [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) because it looks like you don't understand it..

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages:

> `int posix_fadvise(int fd, off_t offset, off_t len, int advice);`
>
> advice types:
>
> ```
>   POSIX_FADV_NORMAL
>           Indicates that the application has no advice to give about its access pattern 
>           for the specified data.  If no advice is given for an open file, this is 
>           the default assumption.
>
>   POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL
>           The application expects to access the specified data sequentially 
>           (with lower offsets read before higher ones).
>
>   POSIX_FADV_RANDOM
>           The specified data will be accessed in random order.
>
>   POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE
>           The specified data will be accessed only once.
>
>   POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED
>           The specified data will be accessed in the near future.
>
>   POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED
>           The specified data will not be accessed in the near future.
> ```

So for entire file, offset and len would be 0.

For your example, I would assume that `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` is what you want to use.